# How would I find what Index the largest number of an array correlates to from a different array?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So this is the code I currently have. First of all, I keep running into an exit code when it calculates the average of all the values. I don't know why this is happening because it was working fine before and I have been editing it to get it back the way it was before but I keep getting the exit code.

After that, I am having trouble displaying the largest value in the array and also displaying the city that it correlates to...
If anyone can help me that would be  great!

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ");
    System.out.println("City\t\tPopulation\t\t\t");
    System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ");

    int[] population = {
      693417,
      457502,
      109985,
      107360,
      103773,
      13145,
      5469
    };
    String[] cities = {
      "Denver",
      "Colo Springs",
      "Pueblo",
      "Boulder",
      "Greely",
      "Fruita",
      "Vail"
    };


    displayPopulations(population, cities);

    int[] total = computeTotalPopulation(population);
    for (int i = 0; i < total.length; i++);

    double[] average = computeAveragePopulation(population);
    for (int i = 0; i < average.length; i++);



  }


  public static void displayPopulations(int[] population, String[] cities) {

    System.out.println(cities[0] + "\t\t" + population[0]);
    System.out.println(cities[1] + "\t" + population[1]);
    System.out.println(cities[2] + "\t\t" + population[2]);
    System.out.println(cities[3] + "\t\t" + population[3]);
    System.out.println(cities[4] + "\t\t" + population[4]);
    System.out.println(cities[5] + "\t\t" + population[5] + "\n");
  }


  public static int[] computeTotalPopulation(int[] population) {

    int[] population2 = {
      693417,
      457502,
      109985,
      107360,
      103773,
      13145,
      5469
    };
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < population2.length; i++) {
      sum += population2[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Total population for all cities is: " + sum);
    return population2;

  }

  public static double[] computeAveragePopulation(int[] population) {

    double[] population3 = {
      693417,
      457502,
      109985,
      107360,
      103773,
      13145,
      5469
    };
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < population3.length; i++) {
      sum = sum + population3[i];
    }

    double averagePopulation = sum / population3.length;
    System.out.printf("Average population for all cities is: %.2f", averagePopulation + "\n");
    return population3;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to return int `sum` for method computeTotalPopulation and double `averagePopulation` for method computeAveragePopulation instead of returning arrays. That is the furthest extend of my hints for you, you will have to figure the rest out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer . In these code you need to know how to use *printf* and *void* and some patterns in java. Hope this can help you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ");
    System.out.println("City\t\tPopulation\t\t\t");
    System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ");

    int[] population = { 693417, 457502, 109985, 107360, 103773, 13145, 5469 };
    String[] cities = { "Denver", "Colo Springs", "Pueblo", "Boulder", "Greely", "Fruita", "Vail" };

    displayPopulations(population, cities);

    int total = computeTotalPopulation(population);

    double average = computeAveragePopulation(total,cities.length);

    System.out.print("Average "+average+" is the variable that have information for we to later use after this code");
}
```

You can use loop to print the element in arrays ,also use printf (print format) to format the sentences ,and use key word *void* then no need to return things.

```
public static void displayPopulations(int[] population, String[] cities) {
    for(int i=0;i<population.length;i++)
        System.out.printf("%-15s %d\n",cities[i] , population[i]);
    System.out.println();
}
```

You can return value for assigning value to the parameter for later use.

```
public static int computeTotalPopulation(int[] population) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++) {
        sum += population[i];
    }

    System.out.println("Total population for all cities is: " + sum);
    return sum;

}

public static double computeAveragePopulation(int sumOfPopulation,int numOfCities) {

    double averagePopulation = sumOfPopulation / numOfCities;
    System.out.printf("Average population for all cities is: %2.2f", averagePopulation );
    return averagePopulation;

}
```

Comment: If you are new to java , [W3c java tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/java/default.asp) is a good place for you to learn and search java .